# Extracting lines from start of files

Tags: shell-script

I have an assignment:

> Write a shell script that copies the first 3 lines of code from all ".c" files in the current directory to a temporary file provided as a positional parameter. The contents of the temporary file are displayed.

Initially I created files ending in ".c", and then I used `head -3 *.c> touch $1` to be able to copy the first 3 lines of each file with that extension, but I want to know if I did okay or could solve in another way.

Comment: Your approach with `head` is good. Just make sure to include that in the question itself next time. The `touch` is not necessary, you can just redirect the output directly to the file. However, you should quote the parameter: `"$1"`

Comment: Thx a lot for help <3

Comment: @Panki Technically, the `$1` in `>$1` shouldn't _need_ to be quoted, but it's required in `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with `head` looks good at first glance, but you will notice how, when you run `head` on multiple files at once, the utility puts a header into the output with the file's name in it.

You might *possibly* want to avoid getting this header, just to follow the assignment text to the letter.

You also don't have to use `touch` at all. I've noticed in attempted solution to other homework assignments that people sometimes think they have to "create the file" first before redirecting data to it, and then they use `touch` to do this.

When you redirect with `>filename`, the given file will automatically be created if it does not already exist (and if permissions in the current directory permits it).  If the file exists, it will be truncated (emptied).

Ok, so how do we stop `head` from producing headers with filenames in the output? Well, if you're on a Linux system, you probably have GNU `head`.  This implementation of `head` has [a *non-standard* `-q` option](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) that suppresses the headers.

The script could therefor be written as

```
#!/bin/sh

head -q -n 3 -- *.c >"$1"
```

... assuming the user has GNU `head`.  Note the `--`. It is needed to signal "end of command line options" to `head` just in case any of the filenames matching the `*.c` filename globbing pattern starts with a dash.  That dash would potentially by taken as the start of an option string.

Another way to do that is to use `head -q -n 3 ./*.c` where `./*.c` explicitly refers to files in the current directory. With each filename being prepended by `./`, no argument has a chance to start with a dash, so `--` is no longer needed.  Which way you do this is up to you, but test your script with a file called `--help.c` in the current directory (`touch -- --help.c`).

I've chosen to use `/bin/sh` as the interpreter for this script, rather than `/bin/bash`.  I did this because the script does not use anything `bash` it needs `bash` for, like arrays, process substitutions, brace expansions, regular expression matching, etc.

If you aren't on a Linux system, or if you want to by compliant to the POSIX standard and write a *portable* script, you should not use `-q` with `head`.

Instead, you may want to loop over the files and use `head` on each individual file:

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in *.c; do
    head -n 3 -- "$name"
done >"$1"
```

Note how we can redirect the output *of the loop* to a file.

You will also note that solving this by using a loop will make the script work even if you have *many thousands* of `.c` files.  Without the loop, you are likely to get an "argument list too long" error when the shell tries to run `head` with the expansion of all those thousands of filenames.  The *downside* is that running `head` against each file individually is rather slow, especially if you have thousands of files.

The next issue is to figure out what should happen if the user of this script doesn't supply a proper argument.  Let's say the user runs this script with a filename that already exists, or with no filename at all.  Lets catch that and complain without doing anything more:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    printf 'expecting 1 argument, got %d\n' "$#" >&2
    exit 1
elif [ -e "$1" ]; then
    printf 'the name "%s" already exist, refusing to over-write\n' "$1" >&2
    exit 1
fi

for name in *.c; do
    head -n 3 -- "$name"
done >"$1"
```

This introduces an `if` statement that firsts test the number of command line arguments given to the script.  If it's not exactly one, complain and exit.  If it's one, but it refers to an already existing name, complain and exit.

Note that diagnostic messages (like errors) should be written to the standard error stream.  I do this here by redirecting the output with `>&2`.  I also terminate the script with a non-zero exit status when it's clear we can't continue.  This makes it possible to test whether your script ran successfully or not:

```
if ./your-script.sh hello world; then
    echo ok
else
    echo something went wrong
fi
```

The remaining issue is to handle the case where there are *no* `.c` files in the current directory.  When this happens, you will notice how your script generates a strange error:

```
head: *.c: No such file or directory
```

This is due to the fact that when a pattern such as `*.c` doesn't match anything, it remains unexpanded.  We can work around this by adding a small test in our loop:

```
for name in *.c; do
    [ ! -e "$name" ] && continue
    head -n 3 -- "$name"
done >"$1"
```

This means "if the file `$name` does not exist, then just skip this iteration of the loop".

If you write this script as a `bash` script, then you could leave the original loop and then set he `nullglob` shell option with `shopt -s nullglob` before the loop to make the shell remove unmatched patterns rather than retain them unexpanded.

Now when you run your script, it will not generate any errors when there are no `.c` files in the current directory, but the output file will be blank if that happens.  If this is undesired, then you may want to test whether `*.c` actually matches anything before starting the loop and redirecting to the output file:

```
outfile=$1

set -- *.c

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
   for name do
       head -n 3 -- "$name"
   done >"$outfile"
fi
```

Here, we first save the name of the output file in a separate variable, because we will overwrite the positional parameters (the arguments given to the script) with the names of all `.c` files (which is done with `set`).

If the first positional parameter is an existing filename, then we allow the loop to run and the output file to be created/truncated.

The loop, when not given anything to iterate over, as in this last piece of code, will iterate over the list of positional parameters by default.  We already set this list to the files with names ending in `.c`.

---

The other variants is to not use `head` at all, but an equivalent command such as `sed 3q` or `awk '1; NR == 3 { exit }'` or some other command.  By using the `head` utility, however, you make it clear what it is you're intending to do.